# How do I turn on OEM on a Samsung Galaxy A03s (Tracfone, SM-S134DL) device?

Tags: samsung, rooting, bootloader-lock

I'm trying to root Samsung Galaxy A03s (Tracfone, SM-S134DL) with Magisk and can't get it to work without the OEM on in the developers option.

How do I turn on OEM?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Based on personal observation on similar questions posted on this site, considering that this is a carrier-locked device, I'm afraid bootloader unlocking is usually blocked by them.

Comment: carrier unlock seems possible for $ 6 with this [tool](https://key-tool.com) up to binary 6 (I am not affiliated)

Comment: someone claim it can be unlocked with [mtkclient](https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient) despites missing OEM unlock https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4493149

Comment: Do not do it! I failed with mine...